# RVM is not a function message when using fish shell

Tags: shell, rvm, fish

I'm trying to use rvm from within the `fish` shell

```
rvm gemset use rails3
```

I'm getting the following error message from fish

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

The same command works fine from Bash.

Comment: See https://rvm.io/integration/fish -- the main suggestion works well for me.